# Lightning Web JavaScript Issue

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

Hi While executing the the JS file i am getting below error.

```
    {
        @track abc = [];
        if (data) {
              let currentData = data.fields;
              this.abc.push({
                value: data.fields.Static__c.value,
                key: 'Static__c'
            })
        }       
        const trs = this.abc.get("Static__c");
    }
```

getting below error:

```
[this.abc.get is not a function]
```

Answer (score 4):

`abc` is an array, not a map. You cannot use get to get value in array of object. You have to use [Array.find](https://codeburst.io/learn-javascript-es6-array-find-array-findindex-7fe4f63c6974)

```
var staticKeyElement = this.abc.find(ele => ele.key === 'Static__c');
console.log(staticKeyElement.value);
```

Sample Playground link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/K_PlRylL/1/edit